# Custom button field blackberry: onfocus, onUnfocus

Tags: button, blackberry

I want to change the colors of background button and the color of text onfocus 
How can I make it?

```java
 class RoundedRectField extends Field {

    // Layout values
    private static final int CURVE_X = 12; // X-axis inset of curve
    private static final int CURVE_Y = 12; // Y-axis inset of curve
    private static final int MARGIN = 2; // Space within component boundary

    // Static colors
    private static final int TEXT_COLOR = 0xFFFFFF; // White
    private static final int BORDER_COLOR = 0xFF8000; // dark gray
    private static final int BACKGROUND_COLOR = 0xFFFFFF; // White
    private static final int TEXT_COLOR_selected = 0xFF6DB6; 
    private static final int BORDER_COLOR_selected = 0xFF8000;
    private static final int BACKGROUND_COLOR_selected = 0xCCCCCC; 
    boolean _focus = false;
    private static String text_button;
    // Point types array for rounded rectangle. Each point type
    // corresponds to one of the colors in the colors array. The
    // space marks the division between points on the top half of
    // the rectangle and those on the bottom.
    private static final byte[] PATH_POINT_TYPES = {
            Graphics.CURVEDPATH_END_POINT,
            Graphics.CURVEDPATH_QUADRATIC_BEZIER_CONTROL_POINT,
            Graphics.CURVEDPATH_END_POINT, Graphics.CURVEDPATH_END_POINT,
            Graphics.CURVEDPATH_QUADRATIC_BEZIER_CONTROL_POINT,
            Graphics.CURVEDPATH_END_POINT,

            Graphics.CURVEDPATH_END_POINT,
            Graphics.CURVEDPATH_QUADRATIC_BEZIER_CONTROL_POINT,
            Graphics.CURVEDPATH_END_POINT, Graphics.CURVEDPATH_END_POINT,
            Graphics.CURVEDPATH_QUADRATIC_BEZIER_CONTROL_POINT,
            Graphics.CURVEDPATH_END_POINT, };

    // Colors array for rounded rectangle gradient. Each color corresponds
    // to one of the points in the point types array. Top light, bottom black.
    private static final int[] PATH_GRADIENT = { 0xFF8000, 0xFF8000, 0xFF8000,
            0xFF8000, 0xFF8000, 0xFF8000,

            0xFC0500, 0xFC0500, 0xFC0500, 0xFC0500, 0xFC0500, 0xFC0500 };

    // Center our readonly field in the space we're given.
    public RoundedRectField(String text_button) {
        super(FIELD_HCENTER | FIELD_VCENTER | READONLY);
        this.text_button = text_button;
    }

    // This field in this demo has a fixed height.
    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return 70;
    }

    // This field in this demo has a fixed width.
    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return 240;
    }

    // When layout is requested, return our height and width.
    protected void layout(int width, int height) {
        setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
    }

    // When painting is requested, do it ourselves.
    protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        // Clear this area to white background, fully opaque.

            g.clear();
            g.setGlobalAlpha(255);
            g.setBackgroundColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR);

            // Drawing within our margin.
            int width = getPreferredWidth() - (MARGIN * 2);
            int height = getPreferredHeight() - (MARGIN * 2);

            // Compute paths for the rounded rectangle. The 1st point (0) is on
            // the left
            // side, right where the curve in the top left corner starts. So the
            // top left
            // corner is point 1. These points correspond to our static arrays.
            int[] xPts = { 0, 0, CURVE_X, width - CURVE_X, width, width, width,
                    width, width - CURVE_X, CURVE_X, 0, 0 };
            int[] yPts = { CURVE_Y, 0, 0, 0, 0, CURVE_Y, height - CURVE_Y,
                    height, height, height, height, height - CURVE_Y };

            // Draw the gradient fill.
            g.drawShadedFilledPath(xPts, yPts, PATH_POINT_TYPES, PATH_GRADIENT,
                    null);

            // Draw a rounded rectangle for the outline.
            // I think that drawRoundRect looks better than drawPathOutline.
            g.setColor(BORDER_COLOR);
            g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, width, height, CURVE_X * 2, CURVE_Y * 2);

            // Place some text in the center.

            Font font = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, 9, Ui.UNITS_pt);
            int textWidth = font.getAdvance(text_button);
            int textHeight = font.getHeight();
            g.setColor(TEXT_COLOR);
            g.setFont(font);
            g.drawText(text_button, (width / 2) - (textWidth / 2) - MARGIN,
                    (height / 2) - (textHeight / 2) - MARGIN);

    }

    protected void onFocus(int direction) {
        _focus = true;
        Dialog.alert("dcd");
        invalidate();
        super.onFocus(direction);
    }

    protected void onUnfocus() {

        _focus = false;

        invalidate();

        super.onUnfocus();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it several ways. One popular way is to provide custom focus drawing in the `paint()` method, which you already override.

You should be able to do this (I'm assuming you declared the `_selected` colors for the focused state):

```java
if (isFocus()) {
    g.setBackgroundColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR_selected);
else {
    g.setBackgroundColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
}
```

...

```java
if (isFocus()) {
    g.setColor(TEXT_COLOR_selected);
} else {
    g.setColor(TEXT_COLOR);
}
```

Those lines go in `paint()`, right where you are currently calling `g.setBackgroundColor` and `g.setColor(TEXT_COLOR)`.

Then, you would override `drawFocus()` and do nothing, since your focus drawing is handled in `paint()`:

```java
protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {
   // override superclass implementation and do nothing
}
```

Finally, you need to make your `Field` focusable, in order to ever receive focus.  You can do so like this:

```java
public RoundedRectField(String text_button) {
    super(FIELD_HCENTER | FIELD_VCENTER | FOCUSABLE);
    this.text_button = text_button;
}
```

If you need the field to be dynamically focusable (sometimes focusable, or sometimes not focusable), then you could implement this method:

```java
public boolean isFocusable() {
```

But, if the field is always focusable, then using the `FOCUSABLE` flag in your constructor will work.  I tested this out, and I saw the text color change with focus (on a OS 5.0 9550).

Comment: I have the colors on the background of button. It a gradient color PATH_GRADIENT = { 0xFF8000, 0xFF8000, 0xFF8000,
            0xFF8000, 0xFF8000, 0xFF8000,

            0xFC0500, 0xFC0500, 0xFC0500, 0xFC0500, 0xFC0500, 0xFC0500 }; and where I add the conditon of isfocus or not

Comment: @fou, Ok, no problem. Then just make two separate calls to `g.drawShadedFilledPath()` depending on whether `isFocus()` is true or false, or declare two different values of the `PATH_GRADIENT` array for focus=true or false.

Comment: my problem where I make the test when I add in paint method         if (isFocus()) {
       g.setColor(TEXT_COLOR_selected);
   } else {
       g.setColor(TEXT_COLOR);
   } nothing happened

Comment: @fou, did you read my comment above (in the answer, after **Edit:**) about `isFocus()`?  Also, what do you mean when you say "nothing happened"?  What color did the text get drawn as?

Comment: i use the both method isfocus or onFocus I change the parameter _focus but the color of button or text didn't change. It still in initial situation

Comment: @fou, ok I think your problem was that the field was not focusable.  See the bottom of my answer, which I just updated. It shows how to make your field focusable.  Also, in my test, using `isFocus()` works just fine.  So, I don't think you need your `_focus` member variable at all.